# What is the hard requirement for a CPU to be supported by Windows 11?

Tags: cpu, windows-11, xeon, windows-11-upgrade

I have a new laptop which happily updated to Windows 11 and an older Lenovo stationary whose Xeon E3-1241 processor is not supported by Windows 11 so it has to happily keep running Windows 10 (except that Windows update nags me).

What is the criteria that my CPU fails so I cannot upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements as given by Microsoft are  at [Windows 11 specs, features, and computer requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-11-specifications).

For the CPU requirements they state:

> 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster with 2 or more cores on a [compatible 64-bit processor](http://aka.ms/CPUlist) or System on a Chip (SoC).

Note that "compatible 64-bit processor" is a link.

It links to [Windows Processor Requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/design/minimum/windows-processor-requirements) where you can find the supported processors for almost every recent edition of Windows.

From there you can find [Windows 11 Supported Processors.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/design/minimum/supported/windows-11-supported-intel-processors) if your processor is not on that list then it is not supported.

Microsoft only support 8th generation or newer, and presumably their Xeon equivalents, on Windows 11.

Comment: Thank you.  I got so far on my own but that doesn't really answer my question _why_ this limitation is there in the first place.

Comment: The why is "because Microsoft said so" and we can't glean anything more than that. It could be that newer processors have better protections and mitigations against SPECTRE and MELTDOWN flaws that mean Microsoft can remove their fudges from the OS and claw back performance, or it could be that the economic crisis meant that CPU sales were down and Microsoft were given an "incentive" to help prop up new sales. Either way Microsoft aren't saying and we can only guess. The long and short of it is that if you want Windows 11 you buy a compatible machine.

Comment: I was hoping that _somebody_ more into Microsoft than me, for some reason knew more about it than just "Microsoft said so and that's final", and thought this was the place.  I agree in your speculation but again, just speculation...

Comment: The only "real" reason Microsoft gave was at https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/06/28/update-on-windows-11-minimum-system-requirements/ where they say that newer processors give "99.8% crash free experience" it's all pretty hand-wavey and completely free of actual facts and still boils down to "because we said so".

Comment: Also has something to do with TPM 2.0 being on those chips.

Comment: @LPChip I have a 6th generation system with TPM 2.0, secure boot and as far as I can tell every other requirement is filled. The only thing I don't have is an 8th generation processor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know exactly what criteria is missing in your computer,
download [WhyNotWin11](https://www.whynotwin11.com/download/).

This utility analyzes each requirement for Windows 11 :

[image]

Comment: Thank you but does this give me more than "It is not on the supported list"?

Comment: It tells you the exact criteria that your computer is missing (and not only the CPU). Try it.

Comment: an older Lenovo stationary whose Xeon E3-1241 processor is not supported by Windows 11   ....  If the CPU generation is older than Jan 1 2019 (3 years) it does not qualify to run Windows 11 natively. Microsoft rules.

Comment: @John But why?  Spectre/meltdown immunity?

Comment: If you have run the program, please add its screenshot to your post.

Comment: @John But why?  ....  No more difficult than Microsoft set rules for its new system. I have both a 9 year old X230 running Windows 11 insider and a 5 year old X1 running Windows 11 Insider.  But only my newer machines run Windows 11 Production.